How do you install an unsigned MSIX package during application development?
During development of a desktop application with Visual Studio under Windows 11, the project creates an MSIX package, which is initially unsigned.
For the purposes of development, I need to install this package locally on the machine to make sure it works.
What steps are required to do this? The install button below is greyed out.
Note: I am aware of what signing is, and I am aware that signing is required before distribution to other machines and the Microsoft Store. My question purely relates to local development. Documentation I have read about the MSIX creation process makes no mention of signing and how this is handled during development.

Developer mode is enabled.


You can install the certificate that was used to sign the msix package as a trusted base certification authority (double clicking the  .cer file will open the wizard to do so).
Of course: only install certificates you know can be trusted!

@JohanDonne There is no certificate that was used to sign the msix package, as indicated in the question the package is unsigned. To be clear this is for development purposes, I want to test if the package works on the local machine. How do devs handle this in the Windows world? I live in the Unix and Mac world, and those are both reasonably easy to understand.

Oops, my bad. In that case, see https://learn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/windows/msix/package/unsigned-package#install-an-unsigned-package
